# Abstracting multiple C# classes

Tags: c#, refactoring, abstraction

I have to deal with a project where someone else has copied and pasted the same class some 12 times, added some customization, but mainly, the structure of the classes are really similar because they were copied from each other.

I am itching to refactor the code because I can't stand looking at the code base.

Is there a tool that can automate some of this headache, that is, extract identical properties and methods into a parent class and make the other classes inherit from it?

Comment: I was that tool once....

Comment: if it's a c# = you can go for 'Extract Interface' option, which is of some help.

Comment: Resharper has a tool to extract a super class from a given class, and it can change all references to the original class; perhaps it might work for multiple classes too ...

Comment: see if Resharper helps..

Comment: The best tool you could invest in now would be a hook to yank that other developer off stage

Comment: @JesusRamos, Asdfg, +1 LOL. pickles just can't now. Definitely will take a look at Resharper and Net Refactor and see which is best.

Comment: Resharper is a beast though, wish I would have had it at the time. I abuse it a little too much now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to arivman, give [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) a shot. 30 day free trial, life-time license available per person (means can take it back home, and to other jobs if they'll allow it).

Comment: There's an [Extract Superclass](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/extract-superclass.html) feature, but the example shown is in Java. Still worth more than a look.

Comment: I have quite a bit of experience with ReSharper and will vouch for it being an exceptionally useful tool, not only for the great refactorings it can perform, but also the static analysis it provides.

Comment: Resharper is an incredible tool, but I don't think they provide comparative refactoring, where you can select multiple classes and have intersecting symbols being extracted. Their *Extract Superclass* creates a superclass based only on a single class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any free solution (other than doing it yourself), but you could give [NET Refractor](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/netrefactorproducthome.html) from KnowDotNet a shot. They even have a 30 day free trial!

Comment: It says `NetRefactor 2.1.70 is the latest version for Visual Studio 1.1`... uhm, what? lol

Comment: LMAO they meant .NET 1.1( i saw another reference to Visual Studio 1.1,2.0 and 3.5 in another page in their site), so it's clear that the web-page author was confusing the framework with the IDE. I haven't tried it on VS 2010 and .NET 4 but i'm guessing their "Extract Superclass" feature ought to work OOB. If it doesn't, try creating a .NET 1 proj, include those 12 classes,comment out any .net 4 code, extract the superclass, and then copy/paste it manually back over.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend you to use a tool like [Clone Detective](http://clonedetectivevs.codeplex.com/) before you opt for the [Natural selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2807396#2807396), there might be more hidden duplication.

Resharper squigglies will definitely give you some hints about code smells and keyboard combos to fix then in a jiffy.

You could also potentially use some bits and pieces from [here](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/working-effectively-with-legacy-code/) and i personally find branching and tagging to be quite effective in situations like these. Any analytical due diligence prior to delving in the code i think goes a long way too.

Answer (score 0):

Here we use [simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/) to find the duplicate code. But again you still need manual intervention 2 remove or 2 update it.